# Why the element of an Integer 2D array is not null by default

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I've been stuck trying to debug my code forever. It would be much appreciated if someone could help take a look and find out what is wrong!

To make it easier to understand, I've declared a 2D array Integer[][] bucket on line 4, and in the following for-loop, I assign value to some indices of the outer array (therefore I believe those indices that I didn't assign value should be `null`);

Then on line 1, I looped through the 2D array and tried to find those `bucket[i]` that are not null, which means I have assigned value to `bucket[i][0]` in the previous loop. However, I got `NullPointerException` because there are instances where `bucket[i]` is not `null`, but `bucket[i][0]` is null.

Here is my code:

```
public int[] topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int num : nums) 
        freqMap.put(num, freqMap.getOrDefault(num, 0)+1);
    Integer[][] bucket = new Integer[nums.length+1][1];
    for(int key : freqMap.keySet()) {
        int frequency = freqMap.get(key);
        if (bucket[frequency] == null) {
            bucket[frequency] = new Integer[1];
        }
        bucket[frequency][0] = key;
    }
        
    int[] res = new int[k];
    int resIdx = 0;
    for(int i = bucket.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if(bucket[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(bucket[i][0]);
            res[resIdx++] = bucket[i][0];
            if(resIdx == k) return res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

I'm so confused why these could happen. I believe for that `bucket [i]` that is not `null`, I have assigned non-null values in the previous loop. Please help me understand, thank you so much!

Comment: Posting code as an image is inappropriate on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have edited my post. Sorry for the inconvenience as I'm new to StackOverflow. And thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What was your motivation for using a `Map` *and* `int[][]` btw? Was it easier access of frequencies, since they are the *values* in the `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

> *"... therefore I believe those indices that I didn't assign value should be null ..."*

No, if you've specified the inner array size during the declaration, then it will be initialized.

You are possibly thinking of a *["jagged" array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array)*, where you don't specify the inner array size.

```java
Integer[][] bucket = new Integer[nums.length + 1][];
```

This will cause the *if-conditional* to match.

```java
if (bucket[frequency] == null)
```

> *"... I looped through the 2D array and trying to find those bucket[i] that are not null, which means I have assigned value to bucket[i][0] in the previous loop. However, I got NullPointerException because there are instances where bucket[i] is not null, but bucket[i][0] is null. ..."*

The confusion you're having is that the contents of the inner array, *Integer[]*, can be null, in addition to the inner array element, *Integer*.

So, the inner array is not null, *bucket[i]*, and the element is, *bucket[i][0]*.

For example, consider the following.

```java
topKFrequent(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3 }, 2);
```

```
bucket[0] = [null]
bucket[1] = [4]
bucket[2] = [3]
bucket[3] = [null]
bucket[4] = [null]
bucket[5] = [null]
bucket[6] = [null]
```

Comment: I can't upvote as I don't have enough reputation. BUT THANK YOU SO MUCH for your comment. If I understand correctly, since I have specified the size of the inner array, which means I have initialized the inner array so they are not null. Do I understand you correctly? Thanks a tonnnnn!!

Comment: @SophyTao, correct, the inner _array_ will not be null, although the elements, or element, of the inner array, are.  You are considering that it is a _jagged_ array, in which, this would be null.  And, no problem, glad it helped.

Comment: @SophyTao, no prob!